# Duplicate Contentful yaml files with Middleman 4 and contentful_middleman

Tags: vagrant, middleman, contentful, middleman-4

When running `bundle exec middleman contentful`, two `yaml` files are being generated, somehow causing both to be deleted from `data/test_space/post`.

[image]

However, a `.tmp` directory with `backups` is being created containing the contentful `yaml` data.

[image]

I've created a minimal test-case at https://github.com/lukeboga/MM-01:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/lukeboga/MM-01.git
$ bundle install
```

**Q:** Why are these files being generated twice and how can I prevent this?

A similar issue seems to have been reported at https://github.com/contentful/contentful_middleman/pull/73, but a fix has been merged...

I'm using:

- Middleman 4.2.1
- contentful_middleman gem, [`dl/upgrade-to-v4`](https://github.com/contentful/contentful_middleman/tree/dl/upgrade-to-v4) branch
- Ruby 2.4.0
- Bundler 1.14.3
- Rubygems 2.6.10.
- Vagrant VM, `ubuntu/xenial` box.

**Update**: For what it's worth, I'm getting the same in ruby 2.3.3

Comment: I'm the maintainer of the gem, could you create an issue or open a support ticket and provide me with you `activate` block?

Comment: Sure - will add shortly. Posted here due to use with vagrant - probably should have tagged that :/... Will make that clear...